# Design help: how to share data between multi-threaded app using Producer-Consumer pattern?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design

Apologies if the title doesn't reflect the problem entirely; I'm not sure how to name the title so please edit if you feel it's necessary.

I have an application that employs the Producer-Consumer pattern. 
In my main thread (Controller class), I create 3 blocking queues and assign them to 3 consumers (each running in its own thread). In a separate thread, I have 1 Producer which assigns data that it receives to each blocking queue. The producer has a Map that knows which types of data must go to which queue (stores a reference to each blocking queue). The Map at times will sometimes be refreshed with new data which can alter which types of data go to which queue. This update must only be done when all the queues are empty so the wrong data doesn't go to the wrong queue which may lead to some out of sequence issues.

My question here is, how to go about controlling this Map? Which class should create and populate the map? The Controller or the Producer or a separate object? Should it be injected into the producer? How do I ensure that when I populate/refresh the Map that it is only done when the queues are empty? Do I have to pause the threads for this? I am trying to design this in a way such that I do dependency injection so I can do some unit testing but I haven't come up with any good designs that I feel strongly about one way or the other. Mostly I'm confused about how to make sure the Map updates don't cause out of sequence issues.

Answer (score 1):

How about One queue per Category of Data?

When data comes through it is placed on the appropriate queue.

The consumer threads are assigned some group of queues via the map. The consumers can only pull messages off of a queue that they have been assigned.

If a consumer wishes to obtain another queue it synchronises with that other thread and they rebalance their queues (assuming they can update the map without interfering with the other consumers). Otherwise it alerts the master thread, and the master performs a global synchronise and rebalance.

Of course this presumes that each category only needs to be done in order relative to other events in its own category.

---

Alternately use a synchronisation value.

When a consumer receives this token on its feed it signals a semaphore, or blocks on a semaphore.

The thread processing data in category X, when it sees the synchronisation token, takes its hands off processing that data, and signals that intention.

When the other thread receives the associated token, it waits for the signal to come through, now knowing that the other thread has taken its hands off. It can then continue processing.

This presumes that you can shove such a sentinel value down your queues.

Comment: Hi @Kain0_0 this is the design I am definitely going for. I feel the master performing a global sync and rebalance is what I had in mind. I'm at a crossroads for some direct implementation patterns. Would it be better for my producer thread to create/maintain this map? Or does my controller class (main thread)? This map gets populated via a call to a DB for global information that happens periodically - so if the Map becomes unbalanced after the DB call I must rebalance across consumers. But this can only be done when all queues are empty. But I'm not sure do I need to pause the threads?

Comment: The map should probably be placed in the message distributor (sounds like master). If the consumers react to the message itself then they really don't care what they receive, so don't need such a mapping, just what to do with each message type.

Comment: The mapping is still relevant so as to prevent another consumer from processing an event with a timestamp that occurred after another event before that previous event gets processed. The main thread spawns the producer thread and consumer threads - where the producer is the message distributor. So it sounds like the map should be maintained in the producer?

Comment: Wow complex. Is it the case that you have a partial ordering on the events/tasks being processed? Is it topical (only one event associated with a topic can be processed at a time, but seperate topics can be processed concurrently). Or is it a more complex Web of all x before any y, where concurrency in x or in y is okay? Different data structures would be better depending on the partial ordering.

Comment: So it's just all events that occur in a sequence x -> y -> z must be processed in that order for a designated "type" of data. I have 1 topic which my producer read's from, inspects the data for a "key" field which it looks up in the map to see which consumer should process it and then send's it on to that specific producer. The map has that (key -> consumer) structure but over time I might not have to handle data for certain key's anymore, which at some point I will refresh that map and must rebalance that (key -> consumer) assignment. That rebalancing is just for evening out the consumption